# Sphinx autoclass with metaclass not working

Tags: python, python-sphinx, metaclass, autodoc

Metaclass:

```
class RequestMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, what, bases, attrs):
        _attrs = {name: decimal_to_string(attr) if callable(attr) else attr for name, attr in attrs.items()}
        return super().__new__(mcs, what, bases, _attrs)
```

When we import RequestMeta for metaclass, Sphinx can't generate members:

```
Class_name(metaclass=RequestMeta)
    def test
        """
        Get test
        :return:
        .. code-block:: json

            [
                {
                "message":"test",
                "timestamp": 123
                }
            ]
        """
```

test.rst:

```
Test
____

.. autoclass:: my_prog.a.Class_name
   :members:
```

Comment: Try inserting a blank line between return and code-block.

Comment: "blank line" won't ever  make any difference in any Python code, but for linter warnings. (and not in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely lies in your `decimal_to_string` decorator. Sphinx won't care about the metaclass, but if in decorating the function you strip its attributes, there is nothing it could do.

Check if `decimal_to_string` is wrapping its target function in `functools.wraps` - that will likely fix your issue.

Comment: functools.wraps  - working!!! Thanks! Problem was with @decorator in metaclass